# Do all continuous real-valued functions determine the topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, category-theory, manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological space. If I know all the continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, will the topology on $X$ be determined?

I know the $\mathbb R$ here is somewhat artificial. So if this is wrong, will it be right if $X$ is a topological manifold?

Comment: Answering a variant question: if instead of $\mathbb{R}$ you take a 2-point space $Y=\{a,b\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset,\{a\},Y\}$, then yes -- the opens of $X$ are exactly those of the form $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ for some continuous $f$. (For every open $A\subseteq X$, we can take $f(x) = a$ if $x\in A$, and $f(x)=b$ otherwise.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Spaces for which this is true are called [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space#Real-valued_continuous_functions). In fact, it is an equivalent characterization of completely regular spaces $X$ that their topology is entirely determined by the set $C(X)$ of real-valued continuous functions on them. In other words, there is a unique completely regular topology that makes all these and only these functions continuous. The standard definition however is this: given any closed subset $F$ and any point $x\not\in F$ there is a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $X$, which is constant $1$ on $F$ but $f(x)=0$. Any regular normal space is completely regular by the [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn's_lemma), and topological manifolds are certainly completely regular.

Comment: To go the other way, the space $S$ for which the topology on $X$ *is* determined by all continuous functions $X\to S$ is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).

Comment: @DerekElkins  Sierpiński space is more likely a term  to refer to the specific topology on two points, I guess?

Comment: @Akatsuki Yes, the Sierpiński space is exactly the space described in chi's comment, i.e. {0,1} with the open sets {{},{0},{0,1}}.  I'm not aware of another (specific) name for it.

Answer (score 24):

Conifold's answer is essentially correct, but you should be careful what you mean by "determine the topology".  Given any collection $I$ of real-valued functions on a set $X$, there is a natural topology you can impose on $X$, namely the coarsest topology that makes each element of $I$ continuous.  Explicitly, this topology on $X$ is the collection of unions of finite intersections of sets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$ where $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open and $f\in I$.

Completely regular spaces are exactly the spaces $X$ such that their topology coincides with this natural topology induced by the set $I$ of all continuous real-valued functions on $X$.  In particular, if you know a space is completely regular, then you can canonically recover its topology from the set of all continuous real-valued functions on it (so in this sense they "determine the topology").  However, this does not mean that its topology is the *only* possible topology on the set with the same collection of continuous real-valued functions.

For instance, let $T$ be the usual topology on $[0,1]$, and let $T'$ be the topology on $[0,1]$ consisting of sets of the form $U\setminus A$ where $U\in T$ and $A\subseteq\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ (intuitively, think of $T'$ as the usual topology modified so that the sequence $(1/n)$ no longer converges to $0$).  Then a function $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with respect to $T$ iff it is continuous with respect to $T'$.  Indeed, suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with respect to $T'$.  Then for any open $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and any point $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ there is a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $\overline{W}\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$, because $V$ contains a closed neighborhood of $f(x)$.  But it is not hard to show that an open set $U\in T'$ contains such a $W$ around each of its points iff actually $U\in T$.  It follows that $f$ is continuous with respect to $T$, not just with respect to $T'$.  (The other implication is trivial, since $T\subset T'$.)

Thus in this example, even though the topology $T$ is completely regular, there is still another topology $T'$ with the same continuous real-valued functions.  All that complete regularity guarantees you is that for any such topology $T'$, $T\subseteq T'$.  (It also guarantees you that $T'$ cannot also be completely regular unless $T=T'$, so $T'$ must be somewhat pathological.)

Comment: There is an example of a  $T_1,T_3$ topology on an infinite  set $X$ for which every continuous $f:X\to R$ is constant.  With the coarse topology on $X$, the continuous real functions on $X$ are also the constant ones.